# Overwriting messy html

Tags: html, css

A friend asked me to fix a html document that was created by several people without any html/css knowledge, using WYSIWYG-Editors. Basically I just want to overwrite everything they did (it's too big of a file to delete every unnecessary line of code) so everything has the same font-color and font-family at least.

I tried using

```
body {
    font-color: rgb(5,51,102) !important;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial !important;
    }
```

(also body* or html/html* )
but it won't change anything. There are a lot of style tags on the individual elements, do these still overwrite !important attributes that have been defined at the top of the document just because they're right on the element? How can I overwrite them?

Just as an example for what I have to deal with:

```
style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: rgb(5,51,102)"><STRONG>Nove</STRONG></SPAN></font><font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" class="welcome-body-font" style="FONT-SIZE: 13px"><SPAN lang=EN-GB 
                                style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: rgb(5,51,102)"><STRONG>mber </STRONG></SPAN></font><font class="welcome-body-font" style="FONT-SIZE: 13px"><SPAN lang=EN-GB
```

This spells "November".

Comment: Good luck with that mess haha

Comment: You should update your wysiwyg and cleanup the code - the font tag is obsolete and should not be used.  You can copy and paste your html into something like this: https://html-cleaner.com/ and it will get rid of your invalid tags and inline styles

Comment: You ought to use some regex combined with find and replace to remove unwanted elements.

Comment: How big a file are we talking about?

Comment: 41k characters. Not the biggest file in the world but too much to go over it manually. At least for a small favour. I'm looking for a quick and dirty way.

Comment: `body*` should have a space between `body` and `*`

Comment: Open the page in a browser, copy the text into a new file and start again. This would remove all styling, but that is good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can override styles using `!important`, but you need to apply directly to element you need to override.

But I would recommend to clean this code (by regex or some programming language), because CSS with lot of `!important` will add more mess.

```css
font, span {font-size: 25px !important; color: red !important}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" class="welcome-body-font" style="FONT-SIZE: 13px">
 <span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: rgb(5,51,102)">
  <STRONG>Nove</STRONG>
 </SPAN>
</font>
<font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" class="welcome-body-font" style="FONT-SIZE: 13px">
 <SPAN lang=EN-GB style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: rgb(5,51,102)">
  <STRONG>mber </STRONG>
 </SPAN>
</font>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do it the hard way. If you want to make it easy for the future you need to simplfy the code and reduce the mess. Sure it will be hard to do at once but you need to do it step by step.

I suggest you to give class name to the elements to assign the CSS and remove the style attributes. This will reduce a lot of HTML codes which will make work easier.